# How to Get the Value of Data in MySql to VB.net 2010 textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

```
TextBox2.Text =  Query = "SELECT access FROM users WHERE username  =" + TextBox1.Text
```

I Really don't know what to do I've been awake for 48 hours solving this one out.. I only have 4 hours till the deadline of this project.. :(

Comment: username may need quotes around it to work in the query
Query = "SELECT access FROM users WHERE username  ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'"

Comment: thanks for answering my question sir but what I wanted to know i how to get the value stored in MySql Database on a specific column then store it on vb.net textbox.. pls sir I really really need this.. :(